# How can I check if XML contains extra tags?

Tags: java, xml, api, post, jaxb

Hello I have a API and I`ve build a POST method that sends and xml and if everything is ok it saves the data in the database. I have a xsd schema and a jaxb class. Can someone give me an example step by step how to check if the xml has extra tags that i dont want ?

Here is the code(this is the jaxb class):

```
package mfp.anaf.dgti.spv.reqformularcontact.v1;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="cui" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integer"/>
 *         &lt;element name="mesaj" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"cui",
"mesaj",
"cateSoli",
"subCateSoli",
"b64"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "resp")
public class Resp {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected BigInteger cui;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String mesaj;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String cateSoli;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String subCateSoli;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String b64;

/**
 * Gets the value of the cui property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link BigInteger }
 *     
 */
public BigInteger getCui() {
    return cui;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the cui property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link BigInteger }
 *     
 */
public void setCui(BigInteger value) {
    this.cui = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the mesaj property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getMesaj() {
    return mesaj;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the mesaj property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setMesaj(String value) {
    this.mesaj = value;
}

public String getCateSoli() {
    return cateSoli;
}

public void setCateSoli(String cateSoli) {
    this.cateSoli = cateSoli;
}

public String getSubCateSoli() {
    return subCateSoli;
}

public void setSubCateSoli(String subCateSoli) {
    this.subCateSoli = subCateSoli;
}

public String getB64() {
    return b64;
}

public void setB64(String b64) {
    this.b64 = b64;
}



}
```

This is the xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns="mfp:anaf:dgti:spv:reqStareMesaj:v1"
targetNamespace="mfp:anaf:dgti:spv:reqStareMesaj:v1" elementFormDefault="qualified"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0" xml:lang="ro">
    <xs:element name="header">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="listaMesaje" type="listaMesajeType"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="listaMesajeType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">          

                <xs:attribute name="index_incarcare" type="IntPoz15SType" use="required"/>          

            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

     <xs:simpleType name="IntPoz15SType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="999999999999999"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

 </xs:schema>
```

And this is the POST class:

```
@javax.ws.rs.Path("/formularContact")
public class SPVFormularContact extends SPVMaster {

Connection con2 = null;

String nume = "NUME";
String cnpcui = "CNPCUI";
String localitatea = "LOCALITATEA";
String strada = "STRADA";
String numar = "NUMAR";
String bloc = "BLOC";
String scara = "SCARA";
String apartament = "APARTAMENT";
String judet = "JUDET";
String email = "EMAIL";
String textIntrebare = "TEXTINTREBARE";
String categContrib = "CATEGCONTRIB";
String secventa = "SECVENTA";
String dataEmail = "DATA_EMAIL";
String categSolicit = "CATEGSOLICIT";
String numeFisier = "NUMEFISIER";
String arondare = "ARONDARE";
String domFiscal = "DOMFISCAL";
String subCategSolicit = "SUBCATEGSOLICIT";
String tipIntrare = "TIPINTRARE";
String stare = "STARE";
String host = "HOST";

String sql = "INSERT INTO ASIST_EMAIL_V ("+nume+", "+cnpcui+", "+localitatea+", "+strada+",    "+numar+", "+bloc+", "+scara+", "+apartament+", "+judet+", "+email+", "+textIntrebare+", "+categContrib+", "+secventa+", "+dataEmail+", "+categSolicit+", "+numeFisier+", "+arondare+", "+domFiscal+", "+subCategSolicit+", "+tipIntrare+", "+stare+", "+host+") VALUES  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
 long secventaOriginala;
 String domF;
 String codA;

 //String cateSoli = "1";
 //String subCateSoli = "1";
 //String categSoli = "1";
 boolean counterCateg = false;
 String cui = "";
 String cuiNou = "";
 boolean b64bol = false;
 String b = "";
 boolean mesajBol = false;
 String mesaj = "";
 boolean categSubCategBol = false;



 @POST
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public Response response(mfp.anaf.dgti.spv.reqformularcontact.v1.Resp x) {
    mfp.anaf.dgti.spv.reqformularcontact.v1.Resp rsp = new  mfp.anaf.dgti.spv.reqformularcontact.v1.Resp();


    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/portal");
        con2 = ds.getConnection();



        Statement st = con2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select emailasist_seq.nextval||to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') from dual");
        while(rs.next()) {
            secventaOriginala = rs.getLong(1);
        }

        Statement st2 = con2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery("select codfisc.cod_domfiscal(1880622420093) from dual");
        while(rs2.next()) {
            domF = rs2.getString(1);
        }

        Statement st3 = con2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs3 = st3.executeQuery("select codfisc.cod_arondare_adm(1880622420093) from dual");
        while(rs3.next()) {
            codA = rs3.getString(1);
        }
        /*
        Statement st4 = con2.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs4 = st4.executeQuery("select categsolicit from nom_categorii where codcateg=1");
        while(rs4.next()) {
            categS = rs4.getString(1);
        }
        */

        spv.ws.caf.ApeluriBaza ap = new spv.ws.caf.ApeluriBaza();

        String serial = "2005062450015C39C6849EAD49A019A5";
        String numeCertif = ap.getNumeCertificat(con2, serial);
        String arr[] = numeCertif.split("###");

        String arondareNou = ap.getArondare(con2, x.getCui().longValue());
        String domFiscalNou = ap.getDomFiscal(con2, x.getCui().longValue());

        String xcui = x.getCui()+"";
        int lungimeCui = xcui.length();
        String categContrib = "";

        if(lungimeCui < 10) {
            categContrib = "Persoană fizică";
        } else {
            categContrib = "Persoană juridică";
        }
        /*
        String adrBz = "C:\\Users\\26225654\\Desktop\\eth.txt";
        String fisier2 = "C:\\Users\\26225654\\Desktop\\nou2.txt";

        Base bz = new Base();
        System.out.println("Base64: " + bz.citeste(adrBz));
        */
        String fisier2 = "C:\\Users\\26225654\\Desktop\\nou3.txt";
        Base bz = new Base();

       JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Resp.class);
       Unmarshaller jaxbu = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

       System.out.println(jaxbu.getSchema());


        if(x.getB64().length() <= 10000000 ) {
        bz.write(fisier2, x.getB64());
        } else {
            b = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
                    "<resp>\r\n" + 
                    "<cui>"+x.getCui()+"</cui>\r\n" + 
                    "<titlu>Formular Cerere</titlu>\r\n" + 
                    "<mesaj>CUI Valid</mesaj>\r\n" + 
                    "<b64>Fisierul depaseste limita maxima de 10 MB</b64>\r\n" + 
                    "</resp>";
            b64bol = true;
        }

      if(x.getMesaj() == null) {
          mesajBol = true;
      }



      if(x.getCateSoli() == null || x.getSubCateSoli() == null) {
          categSubCategBol = true;
      }


        Date xx = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); 

       PreparedStatement ps = con2.prepareStatement(sql);

       ps.setString(1, numeCertif);
       rsp.setCui(x.getCui());
       ps.setInt(2, x.getCui().intValue());
       ps.setString(3, "bistrita");
       ps.setString(4, "xxxx");
       ps.setString(5, "xxx");
       ps.setString(6, "xxx");
       ps.setString(7, "xxx");
       ps.setString(8, "xxxx");
       ps.setString(9, "xxx");

       ps.setString(10, arr[1]);

       rsp.setMesaj(x.getMesaj());
       ps.setString(11, x.getMesaj());
       ps.setString(12, categContrib);
       ps.setLong(13, secventaOriginala);
       ps.setDate(14, xx);
       ps.setString(15, rsp.getCateSoli());
       ps.setString(16, "xxx.pdf");
       ps.setString(17, arondareNou);
       ps.setString(18, domFiscalNou);
       ps.setString(19, rsp.getSubCateSoli());
       ps.setInt(20, 2);
       ps.setInt(21, 99);
       ps.setString(22, "xxx");

       if((x.getCateSoli().equals("1") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("1")) || (x.getCateSoli().equals("1") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("2"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("1") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("3"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("1") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("4"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("5"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("6"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("7"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("8"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("9"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("10"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("11"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("12"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("13"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("14"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("15"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("10"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("16") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("17"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("18"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("19"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("20"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("21"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("4") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("23"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("4") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("22"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("1") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("30"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("1") && x.getCateSoli().equals("31"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("1") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("32"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("1") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("33"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("1") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("34"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("40"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("41"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("42"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("43"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("44"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("2") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("45"))||(x.getCateSoli().equals("3") && x.getSubCateSoli().equals("50"))) {
        if(rsp.getCui().intValue()!=0) {
           counterCateg = true;
        }
    }


//           SPVMaster spvm = new SPVMaster();
//           SPVCerere spvc = new SPVCerere();
           String eroare1 = "Nu am identificat certificatul:" + serial;
           String f = "";
           cui = getCui(serial);
            if (cui == null || cui.length() == 0) {
            String eroare_log = "Nu aveti drept in SPV pentru niciun CUI sau CNP";
            f = writeJsonEroare(eroare1);
        } else {
            if (cui.startsWith("e")) {
                String eroare_log = cui;
                f = writeJsonEroare(eroare_log, "Cerere");

            }
        }
        cuiNou = Integer.toString(x.getCui().intValue());

        if(verificareCui(cui, cuiNou) == true) {


       if(counterCateg == true) {
       ps.executeUpdate();
       }

        }



    }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    finally {
        try {
            con2.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //Master mas = new Master();



    /*
    String output;
    if(counterCateg==true ) {
     output = x.toString();
    } else {
        output = "CUI sau Categorie si subcategorie completate gresit";
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    */
    //String negativ = writeJsonEroare("Nu aveti dreptul sa faceti validare pentru CUI-ul: "  +cuiNou, "Formular cerere");
    //String pozitiv = writeJsonEroare("CUI: " +cuiNou+" valid", "Formular cerere");




    String xmlStr = "";
    if(verificareCui(cui, cuiNou)==true && b64bol == false && mesajBol == false && categSubCategBol == false ) {
    xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
            "<resp>\r\n" + 
            "<cui>"+x.getCui()+"</cui>\r\n" + 
            "<titlu>Formular Cerere</titlu>\r\n" + 
            "<mesaj>CUI Valid</mesaj>\r\n" + 
            "</resp>";

    } else {
        xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
                "<resp>\r\n" + 
                "<cui>"+x.getCui()+"</cui>\r\n" + 
                "<titlu>Formular Cerere</titlu>\r\n" + 
                "<mesaj>CUI Invalid / Lipseste tagul mesaj / categ / subCateg / mesaj invalid</mesaj>\r\n" + 
                "<b64>Fisier Invalid (depaseste limita de 10 MB) sau lipseste tagul b64</b64>\r\n" + 
                "</resp>";
    }




        return Response.status(200).entity(xmlStr).build();

}

}
```

I would like to have a list with xml tags and check it against the tags that the user introduces in the post method and the question is how to get the list that the user introduces in the post request...how to get the xml that he writes..and I`ll manage from there

Thanks in advance

Comment: The easiest way to validate XML tag names (and contents) is to validate against the XSD. Is there a reason why you are not doing that?